# 3 columns with different conditions in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data and need query: grouped date + columns with 3 different conditions for all columns:  `total cases`; `total cases, when refuse_code = 0`; `total_cases, when oper_code = 29`.

```
SELECT   
    date::date as viol_date,
    COUNT(*) as total_viol,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN refuse_code = 0 THEN 1 END) as refuse_0,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN oper_code = 29 THEN 1 END) as oper_code_29
FROM 
    transactions
GROUP BY
    viol_date
HAVING
    date::date BETWEEN '2019-06-02' AND '2019-06-14'
ORDER BY
    viol_date
```

What's wrong with my query? Total cases is normal, but other is too low, like 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Presumably, you want this information *per day* and not overall.

Comment: What format is your date column(might want to pick a better column name)? `Between` can be finicky. Also, for clarity, use `sum` instead of  `count`with your case expressions. Did you mean to use a `where` clause instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should move the date comparison to a where`clause and use`filter`:

```
SELECT date::date as viol_date,
       COUNT(*) as total_viol,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE refuse_code = 0) as refuse_0,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE oper_code = 29) as oper_code_29
FROM transactions
WHERE date >= '2019-06-02' AND date < '2019-06-15'
GROUP BY viol_date
ORDER BY viol_date;
```

Note that I also changed the date comparison so it is more index friendly.

If you want one row for the entire period, then remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_viol,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE refuse_code = 0) as refuse_0,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE oper_code = 29) as oper_code_29
FROM transactions
WHERE date >= '2019-06-02' AND date < '2019-06-15';
```

Answer (score 0):

use `where clause` since you are not filtering anything using aggregation

```
SELECT   
    date::date as viol_date,
    COUNT(*) as total_viol,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN refuse_code = 0 THEN 1 END) as refuse_0,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN oper_code = 29 THEN 1 END) as oper_code_29
FROM 
    transactions
where date::date BETWEEN '2019-06-02' AND '2019-06-14'
GROUP BY 
    date::date
ORDER BY
    viol_date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fahmi! Insta help :)